# What are the DNS 952 subdomain conventions

Tags: dns, openshift

Ran into an error with my Openshift configuration saying my route must conform to the DNS 952 subdomain conventions.

What are they?

Answer (score 3):

RFC 952 is simply at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc952 but itself later revised by other RFCs.

The recent DNS Terminology RFC (8499) gives you the definition and links you need, have a look at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8499#section-2

Answer (score 2):

According to Microsoft's article about [naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/naming-conventions-for-computer-domain-site-ou)

For DNS host names:

> DNS names can contain only alphabetical characters (A-Z), numeric characters (0-9), the minus sign (-), and the period (.). Period characters are allowed only when they are used to delimit the components of domain style names.

and the disallowed characters are:

> DNS host names can't contain the following characters:
> comma (,),
> tilde (~),
> colon (:),
> exclamation point (!),
> at sign (@),
> number sign (#),
> dollar sign ($),
> percent (%),
> caret (^),
> ampersand (&),
> apostrophe ('),
> period (.),
> parentheses (()),
> braces ({}),
> underscore (_), and
> white space (blank)

So if you configure Openshift using a template.yml be sure to not have any extra braces (from parameters), or use any of the other illegal characters.

Comment: DNS host names can not contain ANY characters not being letters, digits, hyphens or dots. I am not sure why this article tries to define a specific list of characters to exclude because obviously it doesn't contain absolutely all characters to be excluded because all **unicode** characters have to be excluded.